# iPad crash log does not have symbolic info

Tags: ipad, crash

I got a crash log from a user, and I do not see any function names - only pointers in hex:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30a29c98 0x30a27000 + 11416
1   UIKit                           0x3517b4ee 0x35167000 + 83182
2   UIKit                           0x3518eddc 0x35167000 + 163292
3   UIKit                           0x3523a84a 0x35167000 + 866378
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32368c3c 0x32366000 + 11324
5   UIKit                           0x3517b5ee 0x35167000 + 83438
6   UIKit                           0x3518eddc 0x35167000 + 163292
7   UIKit                           0x3523a70c 0x35167000 + 866060
```

How can I get the crash log to show more meaningful info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

[Technical Note TN2151 - Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)